# Добавление нового контроллера (на линуксе) к домену на Windows

Tags: linux, контроллер-домена

У меня на работе уже реализована связка доменов винда+линукс и проблем на физических серверах нету.

Однако при попытке сделать тоже самое в виртуальной среде возникают проблемы.

Проблема следующая.
На виртуалбокс поднял две серверные машины (Windows Server 2008r2 and ZentyalServer7.0.0).
WS2008r2 - главный контроллер домена(FSMO) ZL7.0.0 - дополнительный.
При попытке добавления получаю ошибку рассинхронизации времени в 2 минуты, хотя на самом деле сервера синхронезированы по NTP и дата/время у них совпадает секунда в секунду абсолютно!
Скрин прилагаю.

[image: Ошибка времени при включении в домен контроллера ZentyalServer7.0.0]

В логах написано абсолютно то же самое что и на скрине.

Как решить эту несуществующую проблему?

Comment: Проверьте правильность часового пояса в обеих системах

Comment: проверял уже много раз.